# Get the first class from an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, css-selectors

How can I retrieve only the first class `p7` from this HTML element?

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDIV" class="p7 nextclass class_tt">some content</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myDIV').attr('class').first(); //will not work
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#myDIV').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```

`$('#myDIV').attr('class')` returns a string.  [`split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) breaks into an array, using `' '` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to do that:

```
var firstClass = $('#myDIV').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```